# how much data does htop transfer from remote?

Tags: linux, htop

If I am connected by ssh to a machine running htop, how do I calculate how much data the htop process is sending from the remote to the machine with ssh terminal?

For example having htop open for a day connected to a 2xcpu 16gb ram ec2 instance, what sort of network traffic and bandwidth usage should I allocate to the htop process.

Comment: See for example https://serverfault.com/q/389044/37681

Comment: the number of CPU and amount of RAM is irrelevant to how much data htop is generating through SSH